# RazorSQL vs SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql

I have absolutely no problem connecting to my SQL 2008 database remotely when using RazorSQL. However, I have never been able to connect successfully when I try connecting via SQL Server Management Studio. How can I connect with SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. If you have a question, feel free to ask.

Comment: While you are at it, you also might add some more information (like error messages) as well.

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to use the same credentials and the same instance name to connect to the same host for the same database. Oh and if you run your server on a different port then use the same port, too.